# Unable to make different meta descriptions for added Tumblr page

Tags: tumblr, meta-tags

I finally have some time to work  on some SEO on my Tumblr blog. On my main page, I have this meta tag

```
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
```

Now, when I created my new pages, "About", "Portoflio", etc., I obviously want to create different descriptions for these pages. But the tag above automatically gets added on my new pages. Is there a workaround on this? Or am I not doing it right?

edited: I forgot to mention... What I want in my other pages is NOT to take a snippet of the page content. I have specific shorter descriptions that I want to use. But with the tag above, it always automatically takes the snippet.

Comment: AFAIK its not possible. Pages use the text post type. You would need to use a Custom Layout.

Comment: @mikedidthis Yes. That's really the only possible way. The only problem is that I have some Tumblr's in-house fonts I want on my new pages and I can't transfer them if they are custom pages. But thank you for confirming this issue.